# Use MouseArea to change StackLayout Item

Tags: qml, stacklayout, mousearea

How can I use a MouseArea to change the item in a StackLayout?

```
MouseArea {
           id: mouseAreaServerSetup
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked:{
                     // change Iten serverSetupPage
                     }
           }

MouseArea {
           id: mouseAreaClientSetup
           anchors.fill: parent
           onClicked: {
                      // change Iten clientSetupPage
                      }
           }

StackLayout {
             anchors.fill: parent
             currentIndex: menuConfig.currentIndex
             Item {
                  id: serverSetupPage
                  Rectangle {
                            color: "red"
                            }
                  }
             Item {
                  id: clientSetupPage
                  Rectangle {
                            color: "yellow"}
                            }
                   }
             }
```

The idea is that when you click on a mouseArea you change Tab Item

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to assign the `currentIndex` from you stackLayout, so I gave it an `id`. Then each mouse click I increment the `currentIndex` untill it reaches the number of items (`count`).

```
MouseArea {
    id: mouseAreaClientSetup
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked: {
        stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = (stackLayoutMain.currentIndex + 1) % stackLayoutMain.count
    }
}

StackLayout {
    id: stackLayoutMain
    anchors.fill: parent
    currentIndex: 0

    Item {
        id: serverSetupPage
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "red"
        }
    }
    Item {
        id: clientSetupPage
        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "yellow"}
    }
}
```

Btw, I made the Rectangles fill their parent (which is the `StackLayout`) so you will be able to see them actually, they default to a size of (0,0).

I'm not sure why you have put two `MouseArea`, since the first will be overlapped by the second completely and you will never be able to go to `serverSetupPage`. This also touches another problem you might get, if you ever grow away from only displaying a red of yellow `Rectangle` (most probably today ;-) )  and implement another `MouseArea`, that new one will overlap the one to switch tabs.

So page switching is better done by adding a `TabBar` with `TabButton` which will tell what page will be opened. Something like this:

```
TabBar {
    TabButton {
        text: "server"
        onClicked: stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = 0
    }
    TabButton {
        text: "client"
        onClicked: stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,

Your idea works, but it's only one button to change Item to item.

Is there any way to associate MouseArea 1 to Item 1 and MouseArea 2 to item 2 ??

Comment: Please understand that a `MouseArea` is not a visual thing and you have anchored them to fill there parent, which makes MouseArea 1 overlap MouseArea 2, which by extension then doesn't work anymore. Have a look at the TabBar solution I gave

Comment: Amdasis, Thanks,
I have associated the mouseArea to an image.

Image {
source: "images/MediaDestSetup_off.svg"
width: 290
height: 50
 Text {
id: nameMediaDestinationText
 color: "#b5d1db"
text: qsTr("MEDIA DESTINATION")
font.pointSize: 10
 }
 MouseArea { id: mouseAreaMediaDestination
 anchors.fill: parent
 onClicked: {                    
}
 }

Comment: ok, that's fine as well, tip for next time: include such detail in the question. The way the question is now, makes it seem you don't understand the anchor

Answer (score 0):

The solution is use a condicional

```
MouseArea {
  id: mouseAreaServer
  anchors.fill: parent
  hoverEnabled: true
  onClicked: {
   if(stackLayoutMain.currentIndex!=0){
       stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = 0
    }
 }
}
```

The next MouseArea..

```
onClicked: {
if(stackLayoutMain.currentIndex!=1){
       stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = 1
  }
}
```

And the others

```
onClicked: {
if(stackLayoutMain.currentIndex!=n){
       stackLayoutMain.currentIndex = n
  }
}
```